# Can I share my 2TB iCloud storage with my family, using an *individual* Apple One plan?

Tags: icloud, storage

Prior to [Apple One](https://www.apple.com/apple-one/), I was able to share my 2TB of iCloud share with my family; however it seems if I were to switch to Apple One, then I need to opt for Apple One's family option, rather than the individual one, but still share iCloud space with my family.

Does anyone know how it works?

P.S.: I know I'll have to upgrade to 2TB storage in either case, because individual plan comes with 50GB whereas family plan with 200GB.

Also, in Italy (where I live) "Premier" option isn't currently available, so that's unfortunately, not an option for me at this point…